# Are web worker / service worker secure environments to store a password, credit card information, access tokens?

Tags: web-browser, xss, javascript, service-worker

If there is a case where I wish to store sensitive data like a password, credit card information, or access tokens:

Are web workers / service workers a secure environment, where such data can not be compromised?
If so, what to do to really secure it?
If not so, why not exactly?

Comment: they are only as secure as any other part of the site, nothing special.